# Unable to open RTSP link (requesting darwin server) .mp4 file in HTML5

Tags: html

I am trying to play .mp4 file which is on Darwin server
I have tried with my code but its not working
if i open `rtsp://192.168.15.158:554/sample_100kbit.mp4` in VLC player its working fine.
Whats the wrong with this?

my code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video src="rtsp://192.168.15.158:554/sample_100kbit.mp4" width="320" height="240"
 controls="controls">

 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @apaidnerd 75% is acceptable, even Jeff Atwood himself this [thinks](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/#comment-32384) that "anything between 50% and 100% is plenty fine"

Comment: @Nacereddine You're right, I take it back. user1037552, please ignore me and my whiny meddling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser doesn't know how to communicate using the `RSTP` (`rtsp://`) protocol. That's why it works in VLC (which supports it) but not your browser.

Comment: @user1037552 either change the protocol to something your browser understands (like `http`) or you can add support for this protocol using a third party plugin (like VLC for firefox), this plugin must be installed by everyone who views this page (which may be annoying to them).